# Bootstraping an Azure service account in Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-service-principal

I am trying to write the Terraform to create an Azure "service account" and am getting quite confused by the distinction between what Azure AD calls "Applications" and "Service Principals". Effectively, I'm trying to mimic the following Azure CLI call:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/${subscription_id}"
```

The idea would be for a human administrator to run the Terraform, to set it up once, then those credentials could later be used to authenticate for the remaining IaC. (i.e., It's a bootstrapping exercise.)

I wish to do it in Terraform, rather than a Bash script, as it seems more explicit and fits with the rest of my IaC. This is what I have so far:

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_application" "terraform" {
  display_name = "Terraform"
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "terraform" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.terraform.object_id
}

# resource "azuread_service_principal" "terraform" {
#   application_id = azuread_application.terraform.application_id
#   owners         = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
# }
# 
# resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "terraform" {
#   service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.terraform.object_id
# }

resource "local_file" "azurerc" {
  filename        = ".azurerc"
  file_permission = "0600"
  content         = <<EOF
export ARM_ENVIRONMENT="public"
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="${data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id}"
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="${azuread_application.terraform.application_id}"
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="${azuread_application_password.terraform.value}"
EOF
}
```

This runs, but later authenticating with the generated credentials gives an authentication error. Specifically, Terraforms says:

> If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant.

Clearly I haven't done that -- it's commented out in the above snippet -- but that's because this is where my understanding starts to break down. Why do I need both? Why do both the application and the service principal have password resources? If I generate passwords for both, which is the `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET` (I *think* the application password is the right one)? Then there's the role assignment: I see there's an `azuread_app_role_assignment` resource, but I'm having trouble unpicking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to write the Terraform to create an Azure "service
> account" and am getting quite confused by the distinction between what
> Azure AD calls "Applications" and "Service Principals".

***Applications can be seen from Azure AD App registrations blade Where as Service Principals are other wise know as Enterprise Applications. The difference is well documented in this [`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).***

---

> This runs, but later authenticating with the generated credentials
> gives an authentication error. Specifically, Terraforms says:
>
> If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal
> is properly created in the tenant.

***This is because you have no associated service principal to that azure ad application which you have created from Terraform. The association is needed to access the application or authenticating to the azure environment with contributor role. When a App registration is created from portal it by default creates an association of AD app and Service principal , which by default results in creating a service principal for that app registration. It also applies the same concept when we use `az ad sp create-for-rbac`.***

---

> Effectively, I'm trying to mimic the following Azure CLI call:
>
> ```
> az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/${subscription_id}"
> ```

**You can use the below to mimic the above command :**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}
provider "azuread" {}
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_application" "terraform" {
  display_name = "Ansumantest"
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "terraform" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.terraform.object_id
}

 resource "azuread_service_principal" "terraform" {
   application_id = azuread_application.terraform.application_id
   owners         = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
 }

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.terraform.object_id
}

resource "local_file" "azurerc" {
  filename        = ".azurerc"
  file_permission = "0600"
  content         = <<EOF
export ARM_ENVIRONMENT="public"
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="${data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id}"
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="${azuread_application.terraform.application_id}"
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="${azuread_application_password.terraform.value}"
EOF
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

[image]

**Using the above details I created a reosurce group in the subscription :**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
  subscription_id = "88073b30-cadd-459e-b90b-8442c93573ae"
  tenant_id = "ab078f81-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-620b694ded30"
  client_id = "c022ec46-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c72a9b82f429"
  client_secret = "wdV7Q~8Grxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~SCwbRrKIq9"
}
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "name" {
   name = "testansterraform"
   location = "west us 2"
 }
```

[image]